# auto activating embedded sage cell

Tags: jquery, html, embed, sage

I'm trying to embed a small sage cell/program into my webpage. However, the cell only activates when the user presses  a activation button.  I would like the cell to show up automatically on the page so the user does not have to press the activate button and then enter the values in for the program. I don't know how I could do this. Is their any way to auto-press a button that is created by a script? Is their any way for just the cell to show up?

Here is the source code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Sage Cell Server</title>
    <script src="https://sagecell.sagemath.org/static/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://sagecell.sagemath.org/static/embedded_sagecell.js"></script>



    <script>$(function () {
    // Make the div with id 'mycell' a Sage cell
    sagecell.makeSagecell({inputLocation:  '#mycell',
                           template:       sagecell.templates.minimal,
                           evalButtonText: 'Activate'});
                           hide: ['evalButton']
    // Make *any* div with class 'compute' a Sage cell

    });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>


  <h2>Factorial</h2>
  Click the “Activate” button below to calculate factorials.
    <div id="mycell">
@interact
def _(a=(1, 10)):
    print factorial(a)
 </script>
</div>


  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the html for the button generated:

```
<button type="button" class="sagecell_evalButton ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-text">Activate</span></button>
```

Here is the page after the button has been pressed (with the cell):[image]

Comment: could you replicate the same on jsfiddle,http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hide the editor and evalButton.  There is no need for the evalButton text.  Set autoeval to true.  It is set to false as default.

```
sagecell.makeSagecell({inputLocation:  '#mycell',
                       template:       sagecell.templates.minimal,
                       hide: ["editor","evalButton"],
                       autoeval: true});
```